# mysql SELECT 文で、選択的にデータを抽出する

Tags: mysql

id category user_id text という4つのフィールドがあり、user_id が1のレコードを抽出したい。
ただし、同じcategory で user_id が5のレコードが存在する場合、そのレコードの方を優先して抽出したい。

そのような構文を組み立てることは出来るでしょうか?
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

### 解1

whereで`user_id が1のレコード`、left joinで`同じcategory で user_id が5のレコード`を指定することで条件に合う２レコードを1行で取得できます。

```
select a.*, b.*
from table1 a
left join table1 b on a.category = b.category and b.user_id = 5
where a.user_id = 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31d8c/1

結果の例

```
id  category    user_id text    id  category    user_id text
2   200 1   b   3   200 5   c
1   100 1   a   (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
```

最初の４列が`user_id が1のレコード`の情報、5列目以降が`同じcategory で user_id が5のレコード`の情報です。
`同じcategory で user_id が5のレコード`が存在しなければ5列目以降はnullになります。

SQLの結果を取得して5列目以降がnullかどうかを判定すれば目的の結果が得られます。

### 解2

解1のSQLをサブクエリーにして、外側のselectでuser_id=5が存在するかどうかを判定することでも目的の結果が得られます。

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31d8c/3

```
select
  case when id5 is null then id1 else id5 end id,
  case when id5 is null then category1 else category5 end category,
  case when id5 is null then user_id1 else user_id5 end user_id,
  case when id5 is null then text1 else text5 end text
from (
  select
    a.id id1,
    a.category category1,
    a.user_id user_id1,
    a.text text1,
    b.id id5,
    b.category category5,
    b.user_id user_id5,
    b.text text5
  from table1 a
  left join table1 b on a.category = b.category and b.user_id = 5
  where a.user_id = 1
) as sub1
```

Comment: 書き方が悪かったかもしれませんが、単純に1行の結果が欲しいというよりは、categoryの種類が無数にあるため、複数行の結果を返したいと考えています。

Comment: 複数のcategoryがあるとのことなので、複数に対応している解1のみに修正しました。

Comment: サブクエリーを使用してuser_id=5が存在するかどうかを判定する方法を追加しました。

Comment: 解2はサブクエリにしなくてもできますよ。 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31d8c/13

Comment: @rou 確かに仰る通り、サブクエリーは不要ですね。

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  id, category, user_id, text 
FROM 
  your_table 
WHERE
  user_id in (1, 5) 
ORDER BY 
  category, user_id desc
GROUP BY
  category;
```

でいかがでしょうか。（手元ですぐに動作確認できないので、失敗するようでしたら後ほど直します）

user_idが1か5のレコードを抽出し、カテゴリでまとめ、user_idが1と5の両方あるレコードについては5が先になるようにし、最後にGROUP BY categoryで重複がなくなる（5が優先される）ようになるはずです。

Comment: 求めていたのは、まさにこういう事でした。ただし、order by 句をgroup by句の前に持ってくる事ができませんでした。 エラーになってしまいます。そして、order by句を最後に持って来た場合、group化した結果をソートしてしまい、目的を達成できませんでした。

Comment: 実際にテーブルとデータを作って確認しましたが、確かにこれだと①group by できない、②user_id が5だけのユーザーも抽出されてしまう、という問題がありますね。

Comment: いろいろ試してみましたが、やはりSQL自体がとても複雑（長いというよりは、何をしているのかよく分からない）になってしまうため、@tag1216 さんの解１のような方法でSQLで出せるところまで出し、あとはプログラムでなんとかするのが素直かと思いました。スマートな回答ができずすみません。。。

Answer (score 0):

同一categoryにuser_id =1かつuser_id=5のレコードがないセットと、user_id=5のセットを取り出すSQLをunionでつないで作ってみました。
優先抽出の解釈ですが、同一category内にuser_id=5がある場合は、user_id=1のレコードを返さない仕様です。

```
select * from tbl a
where
    a.user_id = 1
and
    exists (select 1 from tbl b where a.category = b.category and b.user_id <> 5)
union
select * from tbl c
where
    c.user_id = 5
```

Comment: existsのサブクエリーですが、この条件だと「user_id=5以外が存在する」となっているのでuser_id=1のレコードがあるので必ずtrueになってしまいます。ここは「user_id=5が存在しない」という条件にする必要があるので`not exists ( ... b.user_id = 5)`が正しいですね。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通りです。